# CSS: How to create vertical and horizontal grids on the same element?

Tags: css

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wf2s8o33/)</kbd>

[Vertical grid can be achieved by:](http://jsfiddle.net/m9t3vf8z/)

HTML:

```
<div class="vertical-grid">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-grid {
  background-size: 20px 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
                                    black 0%,
                                    transparent 5%,
                                    transparent 100%);
}
```

[image]

[Horizontal grid can be achieved by:](http://jsfiddle.net/wLm53dvh/)

HTML:

```
<div class="horizontal-grid">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.horizontal-grid {
  background-size: 100% 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
                                    black 0%,
                                    transparent 7%,
                                    transparent 100%);
}
```

[image]

**Is that possible to have both grids on the same element?**

HTML:

```
<div class="vertical-grid horizontal-grid">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[Enter your answer here]
```

[image]

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wf2s8o33/)</kbd>

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/dx30bry0/

Comment: You can use multiple backgrounds on a single element, read the manual page.

Comment: @MaryMelody Your idea is nice, but it causes the content of the `div` to be outside: http://jsfiddle.net/nxcdgnvg/

Comment: @MishaMoroshko Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/574kLb2a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using multiple backgrounds:

```
.vertical-grid.horizontal-grid {
  background-size: 20px 100%, 100% 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
                                    black 0%,
                                    transparent 5%,
                                    transparent 100%),
                    linear-gradient(to bottom,
                                    black 0%,
                                    transparent 7%,
                                    transparent 100%);
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6Lf7xL6/)</kbd>